# Can anyone help me create a deadlock using semaphores?

Tags: c, parent-child, deadlock, semaphore

I want to make a simple program, where I can show the deadlock in Linux C. This is what I wrote, but obviously it is not the right idea. I want an example where I have a deadlock by using semaphores, but can't figure out how to get to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define KEY 19950914
#define FLAG 0666

int main()
{
    int stop = 1, semid;
    struct sembuf down = { 0, -1, SEM_UNDO };
    struct sembuf up = { 0, 1, SEM_UNDO };

    semid = semget(KEY, 1, FLAG | IPC_CREAT);

    if (semid < 0)
            perror("semget"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, 1);

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
            printf("Child is trying to take resources \n");

            semop(semid, &down, 1);

            printf("Child aquired resources \n");

            do{

            }while(stop != 0);

            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    wait(NULL);

    printf("Parent trying to take resources \n");

    semop(semid, &down, 1);

    printf("Parent aquired resources \n");

    semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID, NULL);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Wrong path. What you're showing is a simple lock conflict. For a deadlock, process A must be holding resource #1 and require resource #2, while process B must be holding resource #2 and require resource #1.

Comment: This may help you to create deadlock using semaphores. http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shivaram/cs537-sp19-notes/semaphore-deadlock/cs537-semaphore-deadlock.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The term *[deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)* specifically denotes the case where multiple threads or processes are all blocked waiting on resources held by each other. So your program doesn't have a "deadlock": one thread is blocked waiting on a resource, yes, but that resource is held by a thread that is *not* blocked waiting on a resource.

Answer (score 1):

A single semaphore will not deadlock unless it is being misused.

The initial setup of a semaphore is that it is zero.

If you have -5… but only 3 processes…. you are misusing the semaphore.

The only way you get a deadlock is that you have one or more processes waiting for it, but no processes releasing it (the invalid situation). If you have one process holding it, then that process MUST release it (or again, it is being misused).